# Single click and select whole word

Tags: macos, click

Is it possible to modify a Mac to select a whole word with a single click (or a modifier key) vs double click?

Comment: Control-Click on a word will highlight the whole word however it also brings up the context-menu, which you can then either select from or press Esc key to dismiss it, but the word remains highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

Control-Click will highlight the whole word (as user3439894 has pointed out) - to prevent the context menu staying open *without* you having to press escape or clicking away, you simply need hold the mouse down for about a second.

To clarify:

- Press Control key down
- Click on word, holding mouse down
- Release Control key or mouse - the context menu should disappear, but the word will remain selected